# MailGun TXT record on "www" is a duplicate to CNAME

Tags: dns, mailgun, googledns

I am using Google DNS and already have a `CNAME` record for `www` to `example.com`. MailGun requires us to have a `TXT` record on hostname `www.example.com` for the `SPF` record: `v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all`

Google DNS complains that `www` is already used by `CNAME` and thereby cannot be used for `TXT`. Anybody with a similar experience? How did you overcome it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sadly this has nothing to do with Programming. Please visit https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Per DNS rules you can not have both a `CNAME` and `TXT` records on the same label at the same time. So you will need to choose between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You intend to send mails from `@www.example.com`? If you do not have an SPF record for `example.com` you can create this one, the `CNAME record` you have means that `www.example.com` will automatically have the same SPF as `example.com`, because `CNAME` means "absolutely the same as" or "alias of"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I created a subdomain (e.g. mg.example.com) in MailGun and configured all the required DNS entries around that subdomain. So the CNAME is on the subdomain.